# Matlab plot: equal distance between ticks

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, scale, axis

I have this 3D plot that I'm making but the data are not linear. This implies that on my plot, the distance between the ticks that I want to show is not equal. How can I adapt the scale of the x and y axis so that this is the case, i.e. so that the axis gets divided into equal parts with the current ticks?

I want the same ticks and tick labels, but that they just have an equal distance in between them on the axes, in stead of small between 0.1 and 0.5 and large between 1 and 5.

The current plot looks like this:

[image: current plot]

```
RMSEval = xlsread('RMSEvalues.xlsx');

X = RMSEval(:,1);
Y = RMSEval(:,2);
Z = RMSEval(:,3);

figure(1);
xi = linspace(min(X),max(X),30);
yi= linspace(min(Y),max(Y),30);
[XI,YI] = meshgrid(xi,yi);
ZI = griddata(X,Y,Z,XI,YI);
contourf(XI,YI,ZI);
colormap('jet');
xticks([1e-13 5e-13 1e-12 5e-12 1e-11]);
yticks([1e-18 5e-18 1e-17 5e-17 1e-16]);
colorbar;
```

Comment: Do you want the tick lines to appear but not the tick numbers?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I guess you can try the following:
`xticks=linspace(min(xlim),max(xlim),n);`
Where n is the number of ticks you would like to show. This however doesn't guarantee you to have integer ticks.
I haven't tested it thou.

Comment: I want the same ticks and tick labels, but that they just have an equal distance in between them on the axes in stead of small between 0.1 and 0.5 and large between 1 and 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plot where the distance between 0.1 and 0.5 is the same as between 1 and 5 would be a log plot, specifically a log-log plot since you want it on both axes. One way to achieve this would be to transform the X and Y values of your data logarithmically and modify the tick mark labels to match the untransformed values rather than the logarithmic ones you're actually plotting.

A rough guess at a solution is below. I say a rough guess because without posting the data you're importing from the xlsx file or a paired down version of that data (as in an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) I can't actually test it.

```
RMSEval = xlsread('RMSEvalues.xlsx');

X = log(RMSEval(:,1));
Y = log(RMSEval(:,2));
Z = RMSEval(:,3);

figure(1);
xi = linspace(min(X),max(X),30);
yi= linspace(min(Y),max(Y),30);
[XI,YI] = meshgrid(xi,yi);
ZI = griddata(X,Y,Z,XI,YI);
contourf(XI,YI,ZI);
colormap('jet');
xticks(log([1e-13 5e-13 1e-12 5e-12 1e-11]));
xticklabels(cellfun(@num2str,num2cell(),'UniformOutput',false));
yticks(log([1e-18 5e-18 1e-17 5e-17 1e-16]));
yticklabels(cellfun(@num2str,num2cell([1e-18 5e-18 1e-17 5e-17 1e-16]),'UniformOutput',false));
colorbar;
```